# Prolongement in Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set of $R^n$, and let $\omega$ be an open subset of $\Omega$ s.t $\overline{\omega} \subset \Omega.$

For $f\in H_0^1(\omega)$, it is known that the extension of $f$ to $\Omega$ by $0$ is an element of  $H_0^1(\Omega).$

I wonder if the result remains true when we replace  $H_0^1$ with $H_0^1\cap H^2$.

Comment: What's going to happen to the normal derivative across the boundary? It's zero outside if you set $f=0$ outside.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not be in $H^2(\Omega)$ in general.

A one-dimensional example: let $\omega=(-1,1)$, $\Omega=(-2,2)$, and $f(x) = x^2-1$. Then $f\in H_0^1(\omega)\cap H^2(\omega)$, but its zero extension is not in $H^2(\Omega)$ (for one thing, $H^2\subset C^1$ in this case).

A similar example works in higher dimensions: take two concentric balls, with $f(x)=|x|^2-1 $ on the smaller one.